# Sistema de cadastro em C salvando em arquivo

Tags: c

Eis aqui meu código. Acredito que os procedimentos de receber strings, receber as informações e inserir no vetor global estejam funcionando, mas o programa para de funcionar ao selecionar a opção listar, assim que é adicionado uma estrutura no vetor global.

O programa funcionava normalmente antes de implementar a função removerQuebraLinha (que funciona normalmente em outros dois programas que testei), mas mesmo retirando ela e recebendo dados diretamente pelo fgets não voltou a funcionar mais.

Sem a função removerQuebraLinha, salvando num arquivo binário as saídas começam aparecer repetidas, ou somadas com outras partes do vetor.

Quando não há usuários / consoles / jogos cadastrados ele lista 0 normalmente. Alguém pode me dar uma luz de onde está o erro? Já tenho revirado esse código há uma semana.

edit: Faltou espaço para as funções gravarVetor() e lerVetor(), então as removi.

edit2: Removi 1/3 das funções, deixando só as interações de cliente no código, já que conseguindo sanar este bug, os demais serão idênticos.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaração das Estruturas a serem utilizadas
typedef struct enderecoStruct
{
char rua[40];
char bairro[30];
char numero[6];
char cep[8];
char cidade[20];
char estado[20];
} Endereco;

typedef struct CadastroPessoaStruct
{
char nome[40];
char reg[12];
char rg[10];
char telefone[11];
Endereco end;
} Pessoa;

//Declaração das variáveis
int input = 0;
int qtdClientes;
int tamClientes;
Pessoa *clientes;
FILE *arquivo;
char clientes_dir[] = "Clientes.bin";

//Declaração dos Procedimentos e Funções a serem utilizados
void menuPrincipal();
void menuClientes();
void menuAlterarCliente();
void removerQuebraLinha();
Pessoa receberCliente();
Endereco receberEndereco();
void inserirCliente();
Pessoa *buscarCliente();
void alterarEndereco();
void alterarNomeCliente();
void alterarTelefoneCliente();
int removerCliente();
void listarClientes();

//Início do main
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    menuPrincipal();
    return 0;
}

void erro(char *nome_arquivo)
{
    printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo %s\n", nome_arquivo);
}

void sucesso()
{
    system("cls");
    printf ("Operacao realizada com sucesso!");
}

void menuPrincipal()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t\t  H&R GAMES!\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|\t                      |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|\t 1 - Cliente          |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|\t 2 - Consoles         |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|\t 3 - Jogos            |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|\t 4 - Vendas           |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|\t 0 - Sair             |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|\t                      |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tPor favor, selecione uma opcao: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        system("cls");
        switch(input)
        {
        case 1:
            menuClientes();
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            printf ("\n\t\t\tOpcao invalida!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
    while(input != 0);
    system("cls");
}

void menuClientes()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t\t  H&R GAMES!\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|\t                      |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    1 - Listar Clientes      |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    2 - Buscar Cliente       |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    3 - Cadastrar Cliente    |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    4 - Alterar Cadastro     |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    5 - Excluir Cadastro     |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    6 - Menu Principal       |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    0 - Sair                 |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|                             |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tPor favor, selecione uma opcao: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        system("cls");
        switch(input)
        {
        case 1:
            listarClientes();
            break;
        case 2:
            buscarCliente();
            break;
        case 3:
            fflush(stdin);
            inserirCliente(receberCliente());
            break;
        case 4:
            menuAlterarCliente();
            break;
        case 5:
            removerCliente(qtdClientes, clientes_dir);
            break;
        case 6:
            menuPrincipal();
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            printf ("\n\t\t\tOpcao invalida!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
    while(input != 0);
    system("cls");
}

void menuAlterarCliente()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t\t  H&R GAMES!\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|\t                      |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    1 - Alterar Nome         |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    2 - Alterar Telefone     |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    3 - Alterar Endereco     |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    4 - Menu Principal       |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t|    0 - Sair                 |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t|                             |\n");
        printf ("\t\t\t===============================\n");
        printf ("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tPor favor, selecione uma opcao: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        system("cls");
        switch(input)
        {
        case 1:
            alterarNomeCliente();
            break;
        case 2:
            alterarTelefoneCliente();
            break;
        case 3:
            alterarEndereco();
            break;
        case 4:
            menuPrincipal();
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            printf ("\n\t\t\tOpcao invalida!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
    while(input != 0);
    system("cls");
}

void removerQuebraLinha(char *string)
{
    if(string != NULL && strlen(string) > 0)
    {
        short tamanho = strlen(string);
        if(string[tamanho-1] == '\n')
        {
            string[tamanho-1] = '\0';
        }
    }
}

void receberString(char *string_destino, int quantidade_caracteres)
{
    fgets(string_destino, quantidade_caracteres, stdin);
    removerQuebraLinha(string_destino);
}

Pessoa receberCliente()
{
    Pessoa p;

    printf("Nome: ");
    receberString(p.nome, 39);
    printf ("CPF: ");
    receberString(p.reg, 13);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("RG: ");
    receberString(p.rg, 11);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Telefone: ");
    receberString(p.telefone, 12);
    fflush(stdin);

    p.end = receberEndereco();

    sucesso();
    return p;
}

Endereco receberEndereco()
{
    Endereco e;

    printf ("Rua: ");
    receberString(e.rua, 39);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Numero: ");
    receberString(e.numero, 5);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("CEP: ");
    receberString(e.cep, 9);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Bairro: ");
    receberString(e.bairro, 29);
    printf ("Cidade: ");
    receberString(e.cidade, 20);
    printf ("Estado: ");
    receberString(e.estado, 20);

    sucesso();
    return e;
}

void inserirCliente(Pessoa p)
{
    if(qtdClientes == tamClientes)
    {
        tamClientes *= 1.5;
        clientes = realloc(clientes, tamClientes*sizeof(Pessoa));
    }
    clientes[qtdClientes] = p;
    qtdClientes++;
}    

void listarClientes()
{
    int c;
    printf("\nListando %d clientes cadastrados\n", qtdClientes);
    for(c=0; c < qtdClientes; c++)
    {
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("(%d)\n", c+1);
        printf("Nome  = %s\n", clientes[c].nome);
        printf("CPF = %s\n", clientes[c].reg);
        printf("RG = %s\n", clientes[c].rg);
        printf("Telefone = %s\n", clientes[c].telefone);
        printf("Endereco = %s", clientes[c].end.rua);
        printf(" - %s,", clientes[c].end.numero);
        printf(" %s,", clientes[c].end.bairro);
        printf(" %s", clientes[c].end.cidade);
        printf(" - %s.", clientes[c].end.estado);
    }
}

void alterarNomeCliente()
{
    int i;
    char cpf[11], nome[40];
    printf ("Digite o CPF do cliente a ter o nome alterado: ");
    fgets(cpf, 11, stdin);
    printf ("Digite o novo nome: ");
    fgets(nome, 39, stdin);
    for (i=0; i < qtdClientes; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(clientes[i].reg, cpf) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(clientes[i].nome, nome);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void alterarTelefoneCliente()
{
    int i;
    char cpf[11], fone[11];
    printf ("Digite o CPF do cliente a ter o telefone alterado: ");
    fgets(cpf, 11, stdin);
    printf ("Digite o novo numero: ");
    fgets(fone, 11, stdin);
    for (i=0; i < qtdClientes; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(clientes[i].reg, cpf) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(clientes[i].telefone, fone);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void alterarEndereco()
{
    int i;
    char cpf[12];
    printf ("Digite o CPF do cliente a ter o endereco alterado: ");
    fgets(cpf, 11, stdin);
    Endereco e;
    e = receberEndereco();
    for (i=0; i < qtdClientes; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(clientes[i].reg, cpf) == 0)
        {
            clientes[i].end = e;
            break;
        }
    }
}

Pessoa *buscarCliente()
{
    Pessoa *p = NULL;
    int i;
    char cpf[12];
    printf ("Digite o CPF do cliente a ser buscado: ");
    fgets(cpf, 11, stdin);
    for (i=0; i < qtdClientes; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(clientes[i].reg, cpf) == 0)
        {
            p = &clientes[i];    
            break;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int removerCliente(int qtd, char *dir)
{
int i, CPF, sucess = 0;
printf("Digite o CPF do cliente que deseja remover: ");
scanf ("%d", &CPF);
for (i=0; i < qtd; i++)
{
    if((clientes[i].reg - CPF) == 0)
    {
        while(i < qtd-1)
        {
            clientes[i] = clientes[i+1];
            i++;
        }
        qtd--;
        sucess = 1;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        erro(dir);
    }
}
return sucess;
}
```

Comment: xiiiiiiiii ... tenta reduzir o código para um pedaço pequeno que tenha o erro. Se eu tivesse que adivinhar diria que o erro vem da mistura de `scanf()` e `fgets()`.

Comment: Deixei o código em função apenas do ponteiro de Clientes. Já que para as outras estruturas o conceito será o mesmo, resolvendo o bug em um conjunto de funções, basta fazer o mesmo nos demais...

Answer (score 1):

Que tal usar o utilitário `gdb` para debugar seu programa em tempo de execução ?

Trata-se de uma ferramenta largamente utilizada para se depurar *leaks* de memória em programas grandes e complexos.

Assumindo que você está tentando encontrar o *leak* de memória no código abaixo, segue um exemplo passo-a-passo de como usar o utilitário.

**1)** Listagem do código a ser depurado:

```
/* programa.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("Antes do leak!\n");

    printf("leak: %s\n", (char*) 1234 );

    printf("Apos o leak!\n");

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

**2)** Compilando seu programa com o `gcc` em modo debug (opção `-g`):

```
$ gcc -g programa.c -o programa
```

**3)** Debugando com o `gdb`:

```
$ gdb ./programa
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/programa...done.
```

**4)** No console do `gdb`, utilize o comando `run` para executar o programa e simular a falha:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/./programa 
Antes do leak!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a61ab4 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
```

**5)** Agora, é só usar o comando `backtrace` para se identificar onde exatamente aconteceu o leak:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7a61ab4 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a6ac99 in printf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004005a2 in main () at programa.c:7
```

Pronto! Segundo o `gdb`, o *leak* de memória ocorreu na linha `7` do arquivo `programa.c` dentro da função `main()`.

Referências:

Wikipedia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger

Página do Projeto: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Espero ter ajudado!